# How virtual functions are called in c++

Tags: c++

```cpp
// b.h
#include <stdio.h>

class Tmp {
 public:
  // virtual void vfunc11() {}
  virtual void vfunc1();
  virtual ~Tmp() {}
};

class Tmp2 : public Tmp {
 public:
  virtual void vfunc1();
};

// b.cc
#include "tutorial/b.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void Tmp2::vfunc1() {
    printf("Tmp2::vfunc1\n");
}


// a.cc
#include "b.h"

int main() {
  Tmp *t = new Tmp2;
  t->vfunc1();
}
```

In the above example, the first time compile `b.cc` and `a.cc` and link them.
At this time, `t->vfunc1();` calls `Tmp::vfunc1`.

Second uncomment `virtual void vfunc11(int);`, just recompile `b.cc`
At this time, the link does not report an error, but the call is `Tmp::vfunc11`

Comment: The C++ standard says nothing about how virtual function are called - it only describes the effect (the most derived version, based on actual type of the object is called). The details are compiler-specific (vary between compilers) but most modern compilers use a form of virtual function table, or vtable, which is (over-simplistically) a set of pointers to functions to call.  When it sees `t->vfunc1()` the compiler retrieves the correct vtable for the object `t`, retrieves the pointer to the function to be called, and then uses that info to call the function.

Comment: The implementation details are not specified by the standard.  Implementations may have different strategies.  The implementation details are not programmatically accessible through the language (unless the compiler vendor supplies an extension that can be utilized, which will be non-portable of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So 'under the hood' each object of a class with virtual function holds data about how to call its version of that function.

That's a logical fact. During execution the code must have a way of determining which version of each virtual function to call for all the concrete object instances it may encounter(*).

In practice that's usually hidden data inside the object and normally a pointer to some data shared by all objects of the same concrete class. That shared data is usually called a 'v-table' because it's basically an array and the code accesses it by subscript. For a class with 3 virtual functions it will have 3 rows including the code entry point of the virtual functions.
What you've done by a partial recompile is to cause code to access the wrong entry in the v-table. The code is calling virtual function subscript 0 and you've replaced it with a different function. Sneaky...

It's working because the two virtual functions (`vfunc1` and `vfunc11`) have same signature (parameters and return type - in this case `void`) so when the code 'accidentally' calls the wrong function, everything happens to work(**).

I strongly recommend that unless you're a compiler implementer that is more than you need to know. Don't go down the rabbit hole of exactly how polymorphism is implemented unless you need to.

(*) It's worth pointing out that good optimisers can sometimes workout which function to call directly. If you instantiate an object as a local variable its concrete class is fixed so which virtual functions to call for it are fixed. Not all virtual function calls go through a lookup. But again, that is detail!

(**) Yes there totally is scope for hacking by conniving to get the wrong virtual function called so have your code malicious code called!

Answer (score 2):

I am gathering that you didn't recompile `a.cc` after changing the header. That is wrong.

With few exceptions that don't apply here, you must always recompile all translation units (`.cc`/`.cpp` files) which include a header that you changed.

Otherwise your program will be broken and it will behave extremely unpredictably.

Technically you are causing undefined behavior, because you are linking two translation units, each with a different definition for `Tmp`, which is a one-definition-rule (ODR) violation.

Comment: I know that normally a.cc and b.cc should be recompiled. But what I want to know is the calling logic of the virtual function, because if vfunc1 is not a virtual function, there is no problem in doing so, and the linker should Will help me find the correct symbol based on the signature.

Comment: `Tmp::vfunc11` has been modified in the example

Comment: @zcfh It is not up to the linker to check signatures, that is the job of the compiler. When you compile b.cc the compiler figures out that it should call the **first** virtual function, so it does. If you then add a new function, b.cc has to be recompiled to see the change, and instead call the **second** virtual function.

Comment: @zcfh Virtual functions are usually implemented via a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) of pointers to the implementations that should be called for an object. You confused the compiler by using different definitions for the class and now different translation units think that different functions are located in different slots of the vtable. This happened here to be the case such that the slot for `vfunc1` happened to actually contain the pointer to `vfunc11`. But all of that are implementation details that can in no way be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a non-abstract function, it *must* be defined (implemented), even if it does nothing:

```
class Tmp {
 public:
  // virtual void vfunc11(int);
  virtual void vfunc1() {}
  virtual ~Tmp() {}
};
```

Otherwise you should make the function abstract:

```
class Tmp {
 public:
  // virtual void vfunc11(int);
  virtual void vfunc1() = 0;
  virtual ~Tmp() {}
};
```

Comment: `vfunc1` is implemented in `b.cc`

Comment: @zcfh `Tmp2::vfunc1` is implemented, but not `Tmp::vfunc1`.